# How to fix 1)Command SwiftDriver emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having issues with Command swift driver.

1)Command SwiftDriver emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
2) Unexpected input file: /Users/surayafarhanaabdulnasser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gout_Mangement_App_Trial_1_7.33.11

3)Unknown dynamically requested build input cannot be found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjtRL.jpg)

I was trying to run the app after copying certain files but ail and error shows as per below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEhoy.jpg)